# tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: tar

I split a huge folder:

```
tar cvpf - somedir | split -b 50000m
```

I then transfered split files to another server and merge it:

```
cat x* > somedir.tar.gz
```

but when I tried to extract the file it shows errors:

```
tar xvf tar xvf somedir.tar.gz tar: This does not look like a tar
archive tar: Skipping to next header tar: Archive contains obsolescent
base-64 headers tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Not a programming question. Try superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: Did you gzip the split files before transferring the parts to the other server?  If so, you need to `gunzip` them before `cat`-ing them back together.

Answer (score 2):

It is not guaranteed that `x*` will expand to the same order in which the files are split.  Assuming the file is split into three chunks then the first chunk would have the `tar(1)` header so you'll have to assemble them back in the same way.

Use `ls(1)` with the `-t` option to concatenate the files in that order.
Hope that helps.